# Add "---OTHERS---" on top of mysql-populated combobox

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

I am having a hard time figuring this out.. I want to add a `"---OTHERS---"` text on top of my `ComboBox`, but my `ComboBox` is populated with MySQL:

```
conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand("select distinct item_type from Company_db.inventory", conDatabase);
try
{
    MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    sda.SelectCommand = cmdDatabase;
    DataSet dbdataset = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(dbdataset);
    cbPart.DataSource = dbdataset.Tables[0];
    cbPart.DisplayMember = "item_type";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the extra item to the rows collection of the datatable before binding it to the datasource.

```
....
sda.Fill(dbdataset);

DataTable dt = dbdataset.Tables[0];
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
row.ItemArray = new object[] {"--OTHERS--"};
dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);

cbPart.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one item to `Items` collection like

```
cbPart.Items.Add(new ListItem("---OTHERS---", "---OTHERS---"))
```

Looks like you are using `Winform`. You can just say like

```
cbPart.Items.Add("---OTHERS---");
```

So in your particular case

```
cbPart.Items.Add("---OTHERS---");
cbPart.DataSource = dbdataset.Tables[0];
cbPart.DisplayMember = "item_type";
cbPart.SelectedItem = "---OTHERS---";
```

Comment: something is showing... 
Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.

Answer (score 0):

You have binded your combo box to the database. So for that you have to add ---OTHERS--- to the data.

```
sda.Fill(dbdataset);
sda.Tables(0).Rows.InsertAt(sda.tables(0).NewRow(), 0)
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

buy just using what @Steve commented

```
sda.Fill(dbdataset);
DataTable dt = dbdataset.Tables[0];
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
row.ItemArray = new object[] {"--OTHERS--"};
dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
cbPart.DataSource = dt;
cbPart.DataSource = dbdataset.Tables[0];    //Plus adding this line
cbPart.DisplayMember = "item_type";         //And this, plus "item_type" is the name of the column
```